# jQuery to add content ONLY in the div I am currently on

Tags: jquery, html

How do I make a selector, which makes jQuery add content ONLY in the div I am currently on?
The divs are in a php foreach loop so I don't want any id's or classes for the divs.

This is the structure of the html:

```
<div>
   <ul class="menu-category">
      <li>Some stuff</li>
      <li class="newrow"></li> <!-- added when clicking on p.add -->
      <li class="edit"><p class="add">Add</p></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div>
   <ul class="menu-category">
      <li>Some stuff</li>
      <li class="newrow"></li> <!-- added when clicking on p.add -->
      <li class="edit"><p class="add">Add</p></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This jQuery script does:
When `<p class="add">` is clicked -> add a row before `<li class="edit">`.

```
// Add new row
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu-category > li ul li p.add').click(function(){
      $('.menu-category > li ul li.edit').before("<li class='newrow'><h6>New item</h6><div><p>Maträtt:</p><input type='text' name='name_[]' placeholder='namn' /></div><div><p>Ingredienser:</p><input type='text' name='ingredients_[]' placeholder='ingredienser' /></div><div><p>Pris:</p><input type='text' name='price_[]' placeholder='Pris' /></li>");
   });
});
```

Problem with the script: It adds `<li class="newrow">` to all divs. I want it only to happend for the div I am clicking p.add on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is to find the `li` relative to the clicked `p.add` element.

In the click handler `this` will point to the clicked `p.add` then you can find out the nearest parent `li.edit` using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.menu-category > li ul li p.add').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('li.edit').before("<li class='newrow'><h6>New item</h6><div><p>Maträtt:</p><input type='text' name='name_[]' placeholder='namn' /></div><div><p>Ingredienser:</p><input type='text' name='ingredients_[]' placeholder='ingredienser' /></div><div><p>Pris:</p><input type='text' name='price_[]' placeholder='Pris' /></li>");
   });
});
```